# How to cycle through 2 arrays and determine if values in each array are the same?

Tags: c++

I am programming a guessing game where the user will define the first array to scale from 1 to whatever number inputed. I have a function that will randomise the numbers, then the second array will be the user input guesses. I am trying to make a for loop that will cycle through both arrays and print "O" if array values match, and "X" if they do not. It looks like the first iteration of the loop works and prints "O" but then prints a lot of X's after that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void createArray() {
    int n;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "Enter total number: ";
    cin >> n;

    // for loop to generate array to scale from 1 - 
       user input.
    int *arr1 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++){
        arr1[i] = i;
        // Counter is used to track the size of array
        counter++;
    }
    // for loop used to print the values of array (just for development and my reference)
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++){
        cout <<"[" << arr1[i] << "]";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << counter << endl << "Number Guessing" << endl;
    cout << "Enter " << counter << " digits (1-" << counter << ")" << endl;

    // initialize user input array to be the same size as first array
    int arr2[counter];
    for (int i =0; i < counter; i++){
        cin >> arr2[i];
    }
    cout << endl;

    // here I am trying to cycle through both arrays and print "O" if the values match in each array.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr1[i] = i;
        bool correct = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            arr2[j] = j;
            if (arr1[i] != arr2[j]){
                correct = false;
                cout << "X";
            }
            if (correct){
                cout << "O";
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main(){
    createArray();
}
```

This is the output:

> Enter total number: 6
>
> [1][2][3][4][5][6]
>
> Number Guessing Enter 6 digits  (1-6)
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6
>
> OXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: array index starts from 0 and goes upto `array_size - 1`

Comment: Change this `for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)` to `for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)`. Arrays are zero based.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete[]` allocated memory as well.

Comment: Scrap the dynamic memory allocation and variable length arrays and replace them with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need two loops

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
  if (arr1[i] == arr2[i]) {
      std::cout << "0";
  }
  else {
      std::cout << "X";
  }
}
```

You should put your expected output for us to know what you want

Comment: I meant to fix this when I suggested an edit, but you should change  the rhs of the == to say `arr2` instead of `arr1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are not comparing the arrays side by side but rather every element in array 1 is being compared to every element in array 2.

Since both arrays are reset by arr[i]=i & arr2[j]=j then they both are {0,1,2,3,4,5}.

The first innerloop will net a 'O' `if(0==0)` where i=0 & j=0, the next 5 innerloops `if(0==1..5)` where i=0 & j=1..5, are an 'X'.

The problem is on the next outerloop. **Correct** is reset to true by the outerloops second pass of i=1, but immediately the innerloop tests `if(1==0)` where i=1 & j=0, which is false and thus sets **Correct** to false.

So on the second pass thru the innerloop `if(1==1)` is true where i=1 & j=1, **BUT** there is no statement in the inner loop to set **Correct back to true.

Also, where as the **X** is printed as the result of the equality test, the **O** is outputted only when **Correct** is still true, which it is not. In fact, for every outloop after the first one, there will be an innerloop equality test which sets **Correct** to false before any a subsequent true equality tests.

The results are one 'O' followed by a 30 'X'. One 'X' for every false; 6 outerloops, and foreach, 5 of the six innerloops will be false. Five of the 'O's will simply not print because the 'O' does not print as a result of the equality test.